# WPF find all regex matches in a xps document

Tags: wpf, xps, xpsdocument

I need to search an expression inside a `xps document` then list all matches (with the page number of each match).

I searched in google, but no reference or sample found which addresses this issue .

SO: How can I search a `xps document` and get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that an XPS file is an Open Packaging package. It can be opened and the contents accessed via the `System.IO.Packaging.Package` class. This makes any operations on the contents much easier.

Here's an example of how to search the page content with a given regex, while also tracking which page the match occurs on.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"th\w+", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);

using(var xps = System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open(@"C:\path\to\regex.oxps"))
{
    var pages = xps.GetParts()
        .Where (p => p.ContentType == "application/vnd.ms-package.xps-fixedpage+xml")
        .ToList();

    for (var i = 0; i < pages.Count; i++)
    {
        var page = pages[i];
        using(var reader = new StreamReader(page.GetStream()))
        {
            var s = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var matches = regex.Matches(s);

            if (matches.Count > 0)
            {
                var matchText = matches
                    .Cast<Match>()
                    .Aggregate (new StringBuilder(), (agg, m) => agg.AppendFormat("{0} ", m.Value));
                Console.WriteLine("Found matches on page {0}: {1}", i + 1, matchText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you mean every language contained in XPS documents. Since we're just doing character pattern matches in the Unicode encoding, yes, it should work for every language.

Answer (score 0):

It is not going to be as simple as you might have thought. XPS files are compressed (zipped) files containing a somewhat complex folder structure containing all the text, fonts, graphics and other items. You can use compression tools such as 7-Zip or WinZip etc. to extract the entire folder structure from an XPS file.

Having said that, you can use the following sequence of steps to do what you want:

1. Extract the contents of your XPS file programmatically in a temp folder. You can use the new [ZipFile class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280(v=vs.110).aspx) for this purpose if you're using .NET 4.5 or better.
2. The extracted folder will have the following folder structure:

   - _rels
   - Documents

     - 1

       - _rels
       - MetaData
       - Pages

         - _rels
       - Resources

         - Fonts
   - MetaData

   Go to `Documents\1\Pages\` subfolder. Here you'll find one or more `.fpage` files, one for each page of your document. These files are in XML format and contain all text contained in the page in a structured manner.
3. Use simple loop to iterate through all `.fpage` files, opening each of them using an XML reader such as XDocument or XmlDocument and search for required text in node values using `RegEx.IsMatch()`. If found, note down the page number in a List and move ahead.